# How to provide a model class with final fields on top of the app?

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

I have this class called ProductModel, and I want to provide this on the top of the app, because I have a couple of screens in different places of the app.

```
class ProductModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final String name, imageUrl, id;
  final double price;
  bool _isFavorite = false;

  ProductModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.name,
    required this.price,
  });

  bool get isFavorite => _isFavorite;

  set isFavorite(bool value) {
    _isFavorite = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I am using provider for state management. I want the isFavorite value updated everywhere whenever it changes. I don't know how to do it. Please help